# Can one cause Page.IsPostBack to be true independently of ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net, security, webforms

If one is checking a user's roles to determine whether they may access a page, is it safe to put this check only inside an `if (!Page.IsPostBack) { ... }`?  Could it be possible for the **client** to cause `Page.IsPostBack == true` independently of ASP.net; that is, the client POST's to the page and sets the right form fields?  If that were possible, then I suppose best practice would be to check security on every page load, not just when `Page.IsPostBack == false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to all those who have answered already, but I don't agree that only checking for security authorization inside a `Page.IsPostBack == false` block is necessarily insecure (**as long as** event validation and encrypted viewstate are turned on).  I have explained why I think this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328618/a-secure-implementation-of-page-ispostback/6342911#6342911), but the short answer is: I don't think you can spoof a postback to a page without first loading it in a non-postback context to get the viewstate and eventvalidation form fields.  The viewstate field returned will cause the content you've hidden inside your `Page.IsPostBack == false` block to stay hidden in any postback which uses that viewstate, and because the viewstate is encrypted it can't be tampered with.

Answer (score 3):

Easily. And it doesn't even have to be via an HTTP post.

IsPostBack checks for the ViewState and Event* hidden fields. If you supply those fields on the query string then IsPostBack will actually return true, so, for example, a client page which tries to load an image using that jerry-rigged query string will cause the code behind to believe it's a post back.

Comment: So are you saying it's basically unsafe to only check for the user's roles when `Page.IsPostBack == false`?  Because, the first request to the page could be a faked postback, and if so, my role-checking code inside the `Page.IsPostBack == false` block won't have been run and so functionality that it would've hidden from the user (as the user doesn't have permission to view it) will appear?

Comment: Yes - always check roles no matter what type of request it is.

Comment: @blowdart Something's just occurred to me; would it be secure, do you think, to check security permissions when a ViewState flag is false (or null), and then set that flag to true?  It's much harder to jury-rig the viewstate, and so the viewstate should only lose that 'true' flag if the page isn't an ASP.net postback.

Comment: @blowdart In fact, to go one step further with that, could we replace the whole Page.IsPostBack mechanism with a Viewstate flag?  On first page load, the flag would be null, but we could always set it to true on Page_Load.  Because they only way to maintain something in the ViewState is to postback, we know that if that flag is already true, it must be a postback.  Again, because it's hard to jerry-rig the ViewState (or is it?), this might provide a much more secure version of Page.IsPostBack?

Comment: You'd have to make sure viewstate was signed, and also only applicable to that user (via ViewState user keys). However why go to that bother? Role checks aren't that expensive and jury rigging security is always a bad idea.

Comment: Because other developers where I work have a habit of putting 'page init' stuff, including security checks, inside a `!Page.IsPostBack`.  If we could universally replace that with a mechanism that really did ensure the page was an ASP.net postback, it would make sense to only check the security when it wasn't a postback, because if it was, one could assume pagestate would maintain the content visibility on the page.

Comment: You can't assume that though. Fiddler and other request generates can replay valid postbacks perfectly and, as I hint at in my answer, you can even do it with a GET tag, enabling CSRF attacks. You should skip role checks anywhere. If you're concerned about methods being called without the user in a valid role then decorate them with [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role="Admins")] - this will force the .NET framework to check roles. Always a good idea anyway, it gives you defense in depth.

Comment: Also what if someone works out what the missing fields are, and inserts them in the browser using a DOM editor. Sometimes event validation catches this, but it's not a panacea.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is that security checks are one of the few things were code duplication is not a bad thing :) (But then again, I would say that, security is my main focus)

Comment: @blowdart But I'm saying that one could invent a mechanism where we assume that viewstate *will* be spoofed, and a valid postback *will* be spoofed.  Given that we assume this, can we still make sure the postback is actually a genuine ASP.net postback by sending a random string as a viewstate entry on first load, and rely on that being posted back in any subsequent postbacks?

Comment: I'm not convinced you *could* make an un-spoofable post back (and no, I don't think random strings would do it - you could certainly use Fiddler to read and then submit), and the time you spend trying to do so would be better put to use doing role checks in the right places :)

Comment: Sure, Fiddler could be used to read the random string *after* it has first been provided, which is my point.  If it then posts that string back as part of a page postback, the rest of the page state has to stay consistent, so it's safe to only carry out the security checks on the first page load, before the random string has been provided.

Comment: I guess, however I still stand by rolling your own would take more time than doing it right in the first place :)

Comment: @blowdart Hmm... hand-crafting a postback to a page may cause Page.IsPostBack to be true, but won't ASP.net's event validation kick in and actually prevent the page from being rendered because the postback event couldn't have originated from the server control that originally rendered it?

Comment: Yes, assuming it's not been disabled. And, err, people do that. Your problem seems to be your colleagues are doing it wrong, so, well, if they're doing one thing wrong, they may end up disabling things too :)

Answer (score 2):

As a concrete example, suppose your page has a button that only administrators are supposed to be able to see and click:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="resetButton" Text="Reset" OnClick="resetButton_Click" />
```

Inside an `if (!IsPostBack)` block in the code-behind, you hide the button if the user isn't an admin:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        resetButton.Visible = IsAdmin();
}

private bool IsAdmin()
{
    ...
}
```

**Question:** Can a non-administrator cause the code in `resetButton_Click` to execute?

**Answer:** YES, even if view state and event validation are enabled.

Someone can simply browse to your page with `?__VIEWSTATE=` or `?__EVENTTARGET=` appended to the URL (causing `IsPostBack` to return `true`) and then click the button.

**Conclusion:** Turning off sensitive functionality in `if (!IsPostBack)` is NOT safe.

To fix the problem, remove the `IsPostBack` check or add `Visible="False"` to the button markup (secure by default).

Answer (score 1):

You'd be setting yourself up for some nasty form attacks if you didn't check in all cases; consider that a malicious user could just build the HTTP request to your server with all the proper form values to make ASP.NET think that its a postback. I would highly recommend checking for user role on every request, postback or not.

Comment: Right, but what I was wondering was how hard it would be for them to build a valid set of form values.  Does ASP.net set some kind of postback ID when the page GET occurs that the client can't know beforehand?  That mechanism would stop malicious triggers of `Page.IsPostBack`.

Answer (score 1):

So, as others point out this is a bad idea, you shouldn't build in holes into your authorization system. In fact, authorization shouldn't happen in pages at all but in HttpModules that look at the request before the page processes it.

To specifically answer the question, unless you use ViewState and you set a ViewStateUserKey value that is unique to your authenticated user then it is easy to make your system think IsPostback is true when it is not. It validates the viewstate and event fields, and the viewstate can be forged. Even if it is encrypted with a machinekey, it's insufficient because the attacker can go to the page themselves, copy the encrypted viewstate and use it in their malicious attack.

In review, peruse how authentication is usually done in the system and use something off the shelf and not hand-rolled.

*** EDIT ***

The long answer: when you're talking about security you want to break it down to the threats and enumerate them. Once you have an understanding of your threats, you can determine your risk from these threats. Once you have threats and risk, you can determine if it is worth mitigating the threat, and how to go about doing it. For example, many people wear seat belts because accidents are common but we do nothing to protect ourselves from alien invasion.

You appear to be concerned about the following threats:

- Unauthenticated users accessing your
  site
- Some user who is authenticated, but
  does not have a required privilege
  seeing some portion of your page
- [Cross site request forgeries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)

To mitigate the first threat, look at the standard off-the-shelf components for doing authentication like the FormsAuthenticationModule which is part of Forms Authentication. These components are built in to ASP.Net and are well designed.

Once a user is properly authenticated to your app, to determine if they have a specific privilege look at Role Based authorizaton and the RoleManagerModule. This will give you the opportunity to associate a set of roles with each identity that was authorized by Forms Authentication.

Finally, you may be unaware but you've stumbled upon another security issue which is a malicious user may convince an authorized user of your application who is at some other location on the internet to cause a POST to occur against your page. The attacker could create a hidden form on a different web page and use javascript to submit it to your web page. If the authorized user is already logged in, then whatever action that should have occurred in the page will occur as the victim but all parameters of the POST are controlled by the attacker (who wrote the code for the form and its values).

To protect yourself against this, the easiest thing to do is use the ViewStateUserKey value I mentioned before and make sure that either EnableViewStateMAC or ViewStateEncryption is used. Encryption is preferred as the HMAC will only make sure an attacker can't tamper with the viewstate but the contents of it is still recoverable. Encryption provides confidentiality and integrity.

Comment: I take the point about authorizing - where possible - before page processing begins, but that only works on a per-page basis.  Surely there is some scope for authorization within the codebehind when you would want to display/enable some content based on a user's level of authorization?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but it still doesn't really address the specific problem I'm interested in.  My problem is closest to your 2nd bulletpoint.  I do indeed use Role Based authorizaton, and the user viewing my page does indeed have roles, and I check them to determine what on the page to show.  My question remains as to when I should be checking those roles; every page load, or only when `Page.IsPostBack == false`.  Is the latter safe to do?

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely possible to POST to a URL independently of ASP.Net.  You don't even need a browser.

You should check out ASP.Net's built-in authentication, authorization, and membership features rather than trying to roll your own.

Here's a good place to start:  https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx and https://web.archive.org/web/20211020140238/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031204-1.aspx

Comment: I know you can POST to a URL, but that's not the same thing as triggering `Page.IsPostBack == true`.

Comment: I see where you're coming from.  It's security by obscurity, in a way.  It would be difficult to construct a POST to fake out the viewstate, etc and trick ASP.NET into thinking there has been a post back.  However, it _could_ be hacked and isn't as secure as it could be.  And since it is rather easy to make it more secure, why not do so?