# Is making an asp:Button control invisible enough to be sure users won't be able to click it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, webforms, authorization

I'm making a simple website that lists files from a certain folder. If the user has admin rights, the user can delete files by clicking the "Delete" button.

In my .aspx file, I have the following code:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Delete" OnCommand="FileList_Delete"
            CommandArgument='<%#Eval("FilePath")%>' Visible='<%CurrentUserIsAdmin()%>' />
```

So the button will not be rendered if `CurrentUserIsAdmin()` returns `false`.

The button is rendered like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$LocalMainContent$FileList$ctrl0$ctl17" value="Delete" />
```

My question is: Can I be sure that this method is safe against a known-code attack if the user modifies the webpage client-side aiming to click this invisible button? Or do I have to take precautions in the code-behind and verify the user's rights in the button-clicked event?

Comment: The button should only be rendered if visible is true.  Otherwise its not included at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, setting a button's `Visible` property to false is enough to prevent its `Click` and `Command` events from being raised, *as long as you don't turn off the default WebForms security features*.

You can easily test this by temporarily adding an always-visible `<input>` element to your .aspx with the same `name` as the rendered `<asp:Button>`:

```
<input type="submit"
       name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$LocalMainContent$FileList$ctrl0$ctl17"
       value="Fake Delete" />
```

Click the fake Delete button when the real Delete button is invisible. You should get an "Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled..." exception.

Important notes:

- Don't set a button's `Visible` property to false within an `if (!IsPostBack)` block because it's possible for an attacker to bypass that check. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27573274/1127114) for more information.
- ASP.NET event validation must be enabled (which it is by default). So don't turn it off by adding `EnableEventValidation="False"` to the `@Page` directive or `<pages enableEventValidation="false" />` to Web.config.
- Never ever ***ever*** disable view state validation by adding `EnableViewStateMac="False"` to the `@Page` directive or `<pages enableViewStateMac="false" />` to Web.config. [This would allow an attacker to tamper with the hidden __EVENTVALIDATION field](http://www.jardinesoftware.net/2012/02/06/asp-net-tampering-with-event-validation-part-1/) and do other nasty things.
- If you choose a derive a custom Button server control from the standard Button control, make sure you add the [`[SupportsEventValidation]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.supportseventvalidationattribute.aspx) attribute to the derived class.
- If you choose to create a custom Button server control from scratch, call [`RegisterForEventValidation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerforeventvalidation.aspx) and [`ValidateEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.validateevent.aspx) in the appropriate places.

Comment: Thanks for security tips!

Comment: Just to be clear, the `Visible` property of a control _cannot be used to "prevent its `Click` and `Command`events from being raised_". Claiming that it does is slightly misleading. From a general security standpoint, it's important to realize that the "invisibility" (not rendering) of a control does not in and by itself prevent a valid `POST` from triggering the event handlers (running code on the server) even with security features enabled. Depending on your specifics, this may or may not still be an issue.

Comment: @OskarLindberg: Can you please provide an example to support your claim?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "example". Obviously, the server (framework, ASP.NET, whatever) does not care much if the control was rendered to the client or not. In principle the server-side application relies entirely on the data in the request to figure out if it's valid and what to do. Easy enough to grab a valid request using Fiddler or something, and then set the control `Visible="False"´, re-issue that same request and watch the application accept it as valid, regardless of the visibility of some button control.

Comment: @OskarLindberg: Your scenario requires that the page be rendered first with Visible set to true. If Visible is never set to true for a particular user and ViewStateUserKey is properly set (which it should always be to prevent CSRF attacks), then do you agree that this user cannot click the button?

Comment: My point is that here is no explicit relationship between the visibility of a certain control and the possibility to raise events. It may be more or less difficult to get (or manufacture) the information needed depending on what security measures are in play, but claiming that not rendering the control in itself "prevents" events from being raised seems inaccurate. `Visibility` is a UI feature, not a security one.

Comment: @OskarLindberg: The purpose of event validation is to establish a relationship between the visibility of a button and its Click event. So long as event validation is enabled and the button is never made visible to a particular user, I believe it's safe to rely on visibility to enforce security. I do concede the fact that if the button is ever made visible to a user, then the user can click the button even if the button would be hidden on a brand new page request.

Answer (score 1):

They simply won't see the button or even 'recieve' it. Your server will not generate any button code sent to the person.

You have to think of it this way. The user never sees any asp code or is able to process it. They only receive html. You can further ensure this by looking at the html and seeing what has been generated.

So in that regard you are safe.

Comment: What happens if you use something like Fiddler to tamper with the request to make it look like the post-back was caused by the invisible button?  I'm hoping that Event Validation or some other server-side process would catch it, but I can't test right now.

Comment: Ah I havent come across fiddler. I too will look into this.

Answer (score -2):

> My question is: can I be sure that this method is safe against known-code attack if user modifies the webpage client-side aiming to click this invisible button? Or I have to make precautions in CodeBehind and verify user rights in button clicked event?

I personally would also put another piece of code in the click event. Verifying that click comes from the user who is authorized to click that button.

What you could also do is to add a button from code behind as this (Assuming you are putting this button into a panel called pnlButtons):

```
Button btnDeleteList = new Button();
btnDeleteList.Text = "Delete List";
btnDeleteList.Click += btnDeleteList_Click;
pnlButtons.Controls.Add(btnDeleteList);
```

In other words, if user is Admin - add a button, if user is not an admin - do not add. In this case you do not have to play around with visibility.

hope this helps.

Comment: This is quite a bit more work, is more error prone, and is no more secure.  There is no way for a user to click a button that is not visible.  It doesn't include the button in the page and use CSS to not display it, rather it actually doesn't send the button's code to the client at all.

Comment: Servy,

- Why would you want to send a button to a client and then disable it via CSS?
- How is making something static (on a page) is more secure rather than making something on the fly on the server side without a client even knowing it?

I am seriously curious, as if I would follow your logic then I was programming until now based on a completely premise and then need to change my habits.

Comment: You wouldn't want to disable it via CSS, I never said that you would.  I said that making it not visible in ASP is not doing that, rather it's actually not rendering it.  Making it static in ASP means that you don't need to concern yourself with re-creating it on every postback, adding in any click handlers in the pre-render phase, and you can write out the HTML using markups, rather than code.  It's *really* easy to not do everything exactly right to have dynamically added buttons properly have their handlers called.  Both methods are secure, so you should use the one that's way easier.

Comment: I see your point. Correct me if I am wrong:

If you have a set number of buttons on your page and you just want to control who clicks what, then the way you are describing is the way to do it. However, if you have a completely dynamic page, where you have no idea upfront how many controls you are going to end up with, then what do you do then? (I am talking for example, displaying files and assigning a button to each file to delete that particular file)

Pardon my edits as I cannot get used to press Shift+Enter to get to a new line.

Comment: No, this is not the best way to do it.  The best way is to just put all of the buttons in the markup and set the visibility based on who has what permissions.  It's *far* easier and less error prone.  This approach is needlessly adding a bunch of additional work and fragility to the program.