# Can a client get to a button click event programmatically if the button is not rendered?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, viewstate

This is in ASP.NET web forms, I have a save button on a screen. When I load the page initially, under certain conditions, the save button is not rendered.

```
button1.visible = false
```

In my button clicked event, I have this

```
public void button1_click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveData();
}
```

The only security preventing the user being from being saved is on whether the save button is rendered.

In MVC, it would be trivial to access the save button action method just by making a HTTP POST to the server with my own modified request.

In ASP.NET Web forms, I'm a little bit confused because it relies on the encrypted ViewState being posted back. Do I still need to add this security to the button1_click event too? If so, then can you tell me how a client can fire a postback to the server that would reach the button click event without the button being visible?

Comment: Definitely an interesting question.  Though regardless of any answer, I'd probably go with "assume the request can be spoofed and always check the authorization".  Security should *always* happen when handling the request, not when presenting the user with the option for the request.  The latter is just UX, not security.

Comment: @david - yeah definitely. I'm more just interested how this could be potentially exploited

Comment: It's "trivial", as you say in MVC only if you fail to implement basic security features, and the same goes for ASP.NET Web Forms. It absolutely _can be potentially exploited_ (unless you rely on a lot of "ifs and buts".)

Answer (score 4):

That is one of the common mistakes about ViewState - it DOES NOT serve your click events and many other things.

Each click on button (or checkbox if autopostback is enabled) raises an form submitting to server. And all info about what was clicked is included in form postback data as plain text. Then server parses this data and, as your button has IPostBackDataHandler implemented, it raises appropriate events like "button id has been clicked". So, you can actually change request body:

```
D__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPD...&ctl00%24_pdContent%24txtEmail=qwe%40aeqw.ry&ctl00%24_pdContent%24btnRtnUser=Login&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWDAL424aUAQLjtYbqCAKu8qTUCQLXm%2BfNAwKk2O%2B4DgK3ypStCAL6q%2BaACgKBnvb9CQLr8ey6CALxoZvDCALFt96ABgLMorjMAwoW3zW69NNlOXygWNnB6luGVWnk
```

Above you can see content of input with id=ctl00__pdContent_txtEmail and clicked login button with id=ctl00__pdContent_btnRtnUser.

More explanation about server events in WebForms [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59t350k3(v=vs.71).aspx).

And please read more about ViewState [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or even better explanation [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate).

Comment: What @LaoR said. You may - depending on your specifics - need to include an __AntiXsrfToken cookie in your request, but the basic point is that all the data you need to successfully trigger the server-side click event and get your `button1_click` method to execute is readily available for the client (browser). This is easily testable using Fiddler or something similar.

Comment: But aren't those ids on the client side? Since the button was never rendered, it doesn't even appear in html. How would you modify that request body to fire the button click? What would the id be?

Comment: @Diskdrive - in any javascript debugging tool one can simply call `__doPostBack` with the right parameters.

Comment: @igor - sure. But the button was never rendered in the html. What would the id be for the client to refer to the button in their dopostback statement?

Comment: if the button is never going to render, why do you have a click event on it? and if the button will be shown after some 'steps' then you can get the ID

Comment: @Diskdrive, as you said it is rendered under certain conditions, so hacker may already know that ID from previous experience. And as **Oskar Lindberg** said, you can simply compose request using Fiddler. Of course, fair user won't try to hack your app, simply cause he do not interested in broken site. But more "motivated" users could easily hack such actions. I would recommend you to implement some authorization logic in your handler.

Comment: @Diskdrive You are correct in that the ID is indeed not rendered if `visible = false`. My arguing that all data is "readily available" may be a slight exaggeration. However, I interpreted your question as "can I safely assume that no one can execute my `button1_click` code with a simple post?", and the answer is still "no". (After all, even in ASP.NET MVC you need some way of finding out  what URI to request to trigger an `Action`.)

Comment: @LaoR : I'm aware you can just modify the request using Fiddler - but I'm saying if there is no button rendered, there is no possible value you can put in to get to the button click event. Client IDs in ASP.NET are generated dynamically relative on each load. An id itself tells the server nothing so I assume these IDs must be mapped to the server events (with the mapping possibly stored in the ViewState?). You can't just use an old ID from a previous page load because that id won't have been mapped as the control was never rendered in the current page load.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24064375/279911 - actually i think someone has already asked this, and it looks like that yes, it is impossible to reach the button click event as long as you have the relevant security settings set

Comment: That answer is misleading. Setting the visibility to false does _not_ prevent the events from being raised. If you already captured a valid viewstate and what not and then re-post a request, of course the events will trigger. Your statements about the client id is not correct - just try it for yourself and you'll see what is possible and what is not.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24064375/279911

According to this answer on another question, it looks like it is impossible to reach the button click event if the button is not rendered as long as you have the relevant security settings set.

> Yes, setting a button's Visible property to false is enough to prevent
>   its Click and Command events from being raised, as long as you don't
>   turn off the default ASP.NET security features.

Comment: I've updated my [original answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24064375/1127114) with one more important thing to keep in mind. See the first bullet point.

Comment: Setting the visibility to false does _not_ prevent the events from being raised. If you already captured a valid viewstate and what not and then re-post a request, of course the events will trigger. The discussion is getting confused, but with my interpretation of the original question here, it's a mistake to serve Michaels answer as correct in this context.

Comment: The key thing to acknowledge in this is that rendering or not rendering the actual button is not a question of security. It's a UI decision. (And the server relies on the posted data to interpret the "state" of the client, the validity of the request and what to do next. What data was issued to the client in the previous response is irrelevant.) It should not be thought of as some replacement for - or even as related to - other security measures.

Comment: @OskarLindberg - true. But in that case, the click event would be using a view state where it is valid for that button to be clicked. The same effect can be achieved (non-maliciously) by concurrent users both accessing the same record at the same time. So yes, I take your point - this is definitely a reason why validation is needed on the event.

Comment: Again, guys, it is not VIEWSTATE, it is EVENTVALIDATION responsible for validating your click. Do not mess it. You can simply disable ViewState but nothing will change in case of clicking that button.

Comment: Yes __EVENTVALIDATION does what it says, and you can skip things under certain circumstances. __EVENTTARGET for example is not needed for things that deals whit POSTing themselves. (Personally, I tend to turn off all viewstate.) However, for the event to trigger, you need to be friends with `IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent`. If `IsPostBack == false` the event will not be raised. By "viewstate and what not" I was referring to "the whole package". In any case, `Visible="False"` is not a security feature, and should not be addressed as such.